# API Gateway resource policy: specify IAM role as AWS principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to setup an API Gateway endpoint with a resource policy, which allows access to a specific IAM role in my account. The IAM role is cross-account, setup with a trust policy which allows AssumeRole to a specific IAM user principal from **another account**.

In the API Gateway resource policy, when I set AWS principal to the role ARN: `arn:aws:iam::********:role/myRole`, I get the following 403 error when invoking the API:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::********:assumed-role/myRole/mySession is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:********:********/test/POST/echo
```

But, if I change the AWS principal to be the temporary STS user ARN: `arn:aws:sts::********:assumed-role/myRole/mySession`, then I can invoke the API successfully.

Here's the resource policy that doesn't work:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********:role/myRole"
        },
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:********:********/*"
    }
]
```

}

Here's the resource policy that works:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::********:assumed-role/myRole/mySession"
        },
        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:********:********/*"
    }
]
```

}

Can IAM roles be used as AWS principals for API Gateway resource policy?

Comment: did you find the answer? i am trying to figure that out too

Comment: Any update?@BrunoNegrãoZica  I'm trying to do the same. No luck so far

Comment: Looking to do the same, please update if you find a solution.

Comment: Did anyone figure out a solution for this yet? I am facing the same exact problem

Comment: More general answer can be found in [AWS IAM role principal vs role session principal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73580439/aws-iam-role-principal-vs-role-session-principal)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-policy-language-overview.html,

> Principal – The account or user who is allowed access to the actions
> and resources in the statement. In a resource policy, the principal is
> the IAM user or account who is the recipient of this permission.

Looks like roles cannot be added as a principal.

P.S: Spent two days trying to restrict access using roles, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by specifying the role in the condition element of the policy (see an explanation below):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:********:********/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::********:role/myRole"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the fragment of the docs with an explanation ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-roles)):

> you can specify the role principal as the principal in a resource-based policy or create a broad-permission policy that uses the aws:PrincipalArn condition key. **When you use this key, the role session principal is granted the permissions based on the ARN of role that was assumed, and not the ARN of the resulting session**. Because AWS does not convert condition key ARNs to IDs, permissions granted to the role ARN persist if you delete the role and then create a new role with the same name. Identity-based policy types, such as permissions boundaries or session policies, do not limit permissions granted using the aws:PrincipalArn condition key with a wildcard(*) in the Principal element, unless the identity-based policies contain an explicit deny.

See also [APIGW resource policy condition keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-aws-condition-keys.html)

So there are two consequences that needs to be taken seriously for sensitive solutions (as stated in the doc):

- If the role is assumed with additional session policies passed (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_session), they won't be evaluated;
- Role replacement attack won't be noticed - if an attacker manages to delete and create a role with the same name (but perhaps different set of permissions), the access will remain. In contrast, when `Principal` element of the resource policy is used, the policy needs to be updated after role replacement to keep an access.