# AWS IAM role principal vs role session principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

AWS documentation for IAM role principals<sup>[1]</sup> states the following:

> To specify the role ARN in the `Principal` element, use the following format:
>
> ```json
> "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:role/role-name" }
> ```

However, when would an IAM policy use a `Principal` element with an IAM role principal, as shown in the snippet? Aren't all IAM actions performed by a role identity actually performed by role session principal<sup>[2]</sup>?

For instance, the following S3 bucket policy has a `Principal` element with an IAM role principal

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/MyRole"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
    }
}
```

but it does *not* grant access to principals who assumed `MyRole`. To do that rather, the policy needs to use a role session principal:

```json
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role:assumed-role/MyRole/MyRoleSession"
}
```

Alternatively, the policy can grant access to *all* `MyRole` role sessions, regardless of session name:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
        "Condition": {
            "ArnEquals": {
                "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/MyRole"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, an IAM role principal is used in the `Condition` element. But returning to the question, is it ever applicable to use it in the `Principal` element?

#### References

1. IAM role principals. *AWS JSON policy elements: Principal.* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-roles
2. Role session principals. *AWS JSON policy elements: Principal.* https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#principal-role-session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on information in ["Resource-based policies and implicit denies in other policy types (same account)"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html),

> | Principal making the request | Resource-based policy | Identity-based policy | Permissions boundary | Session Policy | Result | Reason |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | IAM role | Not applicable | Not applicable | Not applicable | Not applicable | Not applicable | A role itself cannot make a request. Requests are made with the role session after a role is assumed. |

It is impossible for an IAM role itself to make a request, and any policies using the IAM role principal in the `Principal` element

```json
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/MyRole"
}
```

do not apply.

Comment: (1) In my interpretation, what OP is really asking is: when to specify a Role and when a Session Role as the Principal. (2) The doc part referenced in this answer seems to be about only "resource- based policies", whereas the question was general. (3) One of the doc places referenced by OP also states basically the same as the doc part referenced in this answer: "When they use those session credentials to perform operations in AWS, they become a role session principal." (I.e a policy with a Role as Principal cannot be meaningfully evaluated "at runtime" without the Role being actually used.)

Comment: Thanks @n1ghtm4n4g3r! (1) is spot-on, with the added sentiment of "why does AWS even document a seemingly legitimate example of a role `Principal` which in practice never applies?". (2) Since ["You must use the `Principal` element in resource-based policies. ... You cannot use the `Principal` element in an identity-based policy.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html) the question context is indeed limited to resource-based policies, though not explicitly mentioned. (3) Exactly!